# Defining GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES vs getting function pointers

Tags: opengl

I am writing a program which depends on OpenGL 2.0 or above. Looking at the specs of GL 2.0 I see that the extension defined in ARB_shader_objects has been promoted which I suppose mean that the ARB prefix is no more required for GL version 2.0 and above and any implementation supporting > GL2.0 will have this as part of the core implementation.

Having said that when I compile my program gcc on Linux gives warning: implicit declaration of function. One way to get these functions is to declare them in the program itself and then get the function pointers via *GetProcAddress function.

The other way is to define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES before including glext.h which circumvents the problem of getting the function pointers for each of the functions which are by default now present in GL2.0 or above. Could someone please suggest if that is a recommended and right way? The base line is that my program requires OpenGL 2.0 or above and I don't want to support anything less than GL2.0.

Just in case someone suggests to use glee or glew, I don't want to use/ have option to use glee or glew libraries for achieving the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two issues here.

`GL_ARB_shader_objects` indeed was promoted to core in GL2.0, but the API has been slightly changed for the core version, so it is not just the same function names without the ARB prefix, e.g. there is `glCreateShader()` instead of `glCreateShaderObjectARB()`, and  the *two* functions `glGetShaderInfoLog()` and `glGetProgramInfoLog()` replacing `glGetInfoLogARB()` and some other minor differences of this sort.

The second issue is assuming that the GL library exports all 
the core functions. On Linux that is usually the case (not only for core functions, but basically for everything), but there is no standard guaranteeing that. The [OpenGL ABI for Linux](http://www.opengl.org/registry/ABI/) just requires:

> 3.4. The libraries must export all OpenGL 1.2, GLU 1.3, GLX 1.3, and ARB_multitexture entry points statically.

There are [proposals for an update](http://lwn.net/Articles/518394/) but I haven't heard anything about that recently.

Windows only exports OpenGL 1.1 core, as the opengl32.dll is part of the OS and the ICD is in a separate dll. You have to query the function pointers for virtually everything there.

So the most portable way is definitively to query the stuff, no matter if you do it manually or use some library like glew.

Comment: IIRC Vista and above improved the situation *slightly* by exporting 1.4.

Comment: @genpfault: no, they haven't. Vista just uses D3D instead of a sw rasterizer for the default 1.1 renderer, but otherwise, it is still the same. GL1.1 is simply part of the Win32 API and has never been updated.

Comment: What about defining the GL_EXT_PROTOTYPES and using the functions without doing GetProcAddress for all of them? Is it not recommended? If not then why at all it is part of glext headers? Moreover for core functionality if one has to do GetProcAddress all the time, then what is the purpose of having them promoted as core functionality?

Comment: moreover the OpenGL ABI for Linux link that you have pointed dates back to 2000 while the OpenGL2.1 specs are dated 2004. So the document is valid for era before programmable pipeline but probably not for GL2.x and above.

Comment: @DivKis01: the fact that you can declare the function prototypes does not magically create library export symbols on all potentially existing implementations. Stuff getting promoted to core just means that it is in the spec and guaranteed to be available on all conformant implementations. The OpenGL ABI I linked is just the latest there is. I even linked to the propsed updates. GL2.0 beeing newer does not change anything here either. Why should it invalidate it. As long as you don't find something like a standard stating that GL2.x functions must be exported, you simply can't rely on it.

Comment: I see your point. But assuming I only care for Linux and I am not bothered about my program running on Win* systems, is simply defining the GL_EXT_PROTOTYPES recommended?

Comment: @DivKis01: I've never seen any recommendation like that. Usually, the recommendation is to use the extension mechanism... OTOH, I've never seen a Linux GL implementation which did not export all the functions it supports. Your code will fail to start with a linker error if run on machine which lacks a particular feature/extension, no chance to use fallback paths. The existence of the function does not imply that it is supported (only the extension/version string matter). Mesa seems to export a generic set of functions in libGL.so while the backend driver does not implement them all...

Comment: @derhass: >>Mesa seems to export a generic set of functions in >>libGL.so while the backend driver does not implement them all
I am not sure what you mean here. Do you mean that a program compiled against mesa headers will link but not run? Or do you mean it will compile and run but will not produce the expected output?